# Versioning of Models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, versioning, acts-as-versioned, vestal-versions

I'm looking for a plugin/act to allow versioning of my models. It's kind of difficult to find a list of the available solutions. So far I gathered:

- `acts_as_versioned`
- `simply_versioned`
- `vestal_versions`

The last two solutions only require a single version table - this sounds nice, but I've got a bad feeling about how the ease of migrations will be affacted by this (because they serialize states as a string).

On the other hand, `acts_as_versioned` is a little bit dusty (last commit in January). Are there any recent experiences with any of these? Or other solutions (or forks) I might have overlooked?

Comment: Questions like this are what Ruby Toolbox was created for: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning.  As this question ages and gems come and go, Ruby Toolbox will remain a good resource to show consistent go-tos, up-and-coming alternatives, popularity and maintenance of various projects.  All you need to make your decision!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've worked with `vestal_versions` last week and yes, it is the most advanced alternative, at least in terms of space: you store just what you really need. It is an active project and the version 1.0 is going to be a huge update with many new features; just look at the 1.0 branch to know what I mean.

But after playing with it a bit, I've noticed a big flaw: performance. Every time you need an specific version, you have to go through all intermediate ones, reconstructing the version you need. This also means you cannot edit or delete a version directly, because it can mess with modifications, broking the chain. For do this, you need to process versions adequately, what `vestal_versions` currently does not do.

This way, for the problem I had, I ended up with my own versioning solution. I needed performance and the ability to delete and edit versions rapidly, so I sacrificed storage and developed something similiar to `act_as_versioned`.

BUT, if you don't need this and do not have to revert very frequently, I highly recommend `vestal_versions`. It is an advanced, solid solution and an active one, with a passionate developer behind it.

Comment: I took a look at all the solutions (paper trail, acts_as_audited) and finally chose to go the same way as Lailson - to develop yet another versioning plugin (sirlantis/historical at github, work in progress).

Comment: Just to clarify: I did not build a library, I just make a custom solution for my problem. But good luck with the plugin. I see you did a lot of things really fast, with nice documentation. It looks promising… I'm interested on this matter and I'll keep watching your project.

Answer (score 21):

Ive been working with a gem called "paper_trail". It seems to be the best solution online at the moment. It has auditing and version control in one.

http://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have chosen to go with paper trail as well.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of months ago I tested a couple of solutions and `vestal_versions` was the most effective.
There's also a [great screencast here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/177-model-versioning) from Ryan Bates.

If you are looking for other alternatives, check out [The Ruby Toolbox list](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning).

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be the most advanced one. Maybe I'm wrong about how it handles migrations, I'll do some tests. And thanks for the Toolbox link!

Answer (score 2):

We used acts_as_audited in a project, with quite a good success.

You can find that at http://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited/

(last commit in november :-) )

Comment: Looks promising - i'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Another plugin is paper_trail. Here is a link to the railscasts posted today:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail

He also mentions why he prefers paper_trail over vestal_versions

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I'm wondering if anyone has thought of using Perforce, GitHub, etc. on the backend INSTEAD of a database as a way to support versioning?  So it would essentially be file-based retrieval of data, I guess...

Comment: Actually, instead of "using p4, etc. INSTEAD of a database," how about versioning/branching the database using p4, etc. by having the Rails session direct the versioning.  For example, I want to check out model v4.1 so before accessing data from the database, I check out that version of the database.  If I want to branch, I first issue a branch command, then keep working.  Thoughts?