# Rails record versioning solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, versioning

I'm looking for a solution to version database changes in rails. Looking for something very basic.

I mean like a wiki or SO edit versioning.

Comment: Note to readers: This question could perhaps be a little more clear -- it's asking about something for versioning *database content*, i.e. rows in the database, not just the *structure* of the database (e.g. migrations and source control around them).

Comment: Here is another thread on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697456/versioning-of-models-in-ruby-on-rails Two screencasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/177-model-versioning
http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail Paper trail looks the best from my research.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Acts as versioned](http://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned) will version your models automagically.

The [Ruby Toolbox](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com) lists solutions for things like this ordered by popularity. There is a category on [ActiveRecord versioning](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning) you might want to check out.